# What is the (Asynchronous Control Signals Information) subsection in the Xilinx ISE synthesis timing report supposed to include?

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, xilinx-ise

I wrote a simple VHDL code for a DFF with an asynchronous reset input here:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity DFF is
    port (d: in  STD_LOGIC;
          q: out  STD_LOGIC;
          clk: in  STD_LOGIC;
          reset: in  STD_LOGIC);
end DFF;

architecture Behavioral of DFF is
begin
    process (reset, clk) begin
        if (reset = '1') then 
            q <= '0';
        elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then 
            q <= d;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Which HAS an asynchronous reset "control" pin.
There is a subsection in the Timing Report called "Asynchronous Control Signals Information"
This is its content:

```
Asynchronous Control Signals Information:
----------------------------------------
No asynchronous control signals found in this design
```

If this section does not include the asynchronous reset, what should it include?

Comment: check this https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Timing-Analysis/no-asynch-signals-in-time-report-meaning/m-p/755237#M11278

Comment: @AhmadZaklouta Thank you!